# Is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess pooling per application or per server?

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

I understand that the connections pools are created from the connectionstring.

I run 2 differents applications both using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and both using the same connectionstring.
Do I get 1 pool per application or 1 common to both ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.OracleInternal.ConnectionPool, the pools are not mutualized through multiple applications.